# Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.test/com.sense.service } U=0: not found

Tags: android, android-service-binding

The mentioned error occurs when I launch an android Service, which is placed in jar file, which is nothing but another library.

If use library as an source package then it's working fine.
any suggestion there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this to manifest check

```
 <service android:name="com.telbru.android.ebill.GcmIntentService" >
        </service>
```